# css 'display none' does not work in first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Now I'm developing a slide show application with jquery.transit. What I want to do is to hide a photo after its showing animation. So I set properties of display, transform and translate to 'none' value. Then, the slide show application works well, but I noticed display: none is not set in js console in Chrome. After some trials, I found a way to enable display: none for setting twice in my code.
Does anyone know what is the problems in my code? Maybe my js code has some problems.

```
  function showPhoto() {
    photo_list[counter]
      .css({
        scale   : 2,
        display : 'inline'
      })
      .transition({
        opacity : 1
      }, 1000)
      .transition({
        x : '+=20',
        y : '+=30',
        scale: 2.3
      }, 1500)
      .transition({
        opacity: 0
      }, 500, 'linear', function() {
        $(this)
          .css({
            diaplay   : 'none',
            transform : 'none',
            translate : 'none',
            x         : 0,
            y         : 0,
            scale     : 1
          });
        $(this).css({display: 'none'}); // it works, but its redundant 
        incrDomIndex();
        showPhoto();
      });
  };
```

photo_list is an Array object of a img dom, and each has a class in below.

```
.photo {
  position : absolute;
  top      : 0;
  left     : 0;
  width    : 800px;
  height   : 500px;
}
```

Comment: Typo mistake in `diaplay : 'none',`

Comment: `diaplay  !=  display`

Comment: How embarrassing! This problems is just a typo. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $(this)
      .css({
        diaplay   : 'none', // Mistake here
        transform : 'none',
        translate : 'none',
        x         : 0,
        y         : 0,
        scale     : 1
      });
    $(this).css({display: 'none'}); // it works, but its redundant 
    incrDomIndex();
    showPhoto();
```

Change **diaplay** to **display** and see if that fixes both errors for you.